# In Firebase Functions showing Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail - error message

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I do receive an error message while deploying.
In Firebase Functions showing Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail

I have already define all the apikey etc but the database is not linked dialogflow.

Please advise.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var config = {  
apiKey: xxxxx,
authDomain: xxxxx,
databaseURL: xxxxx,
projectId: xxxxx,
storageBucket: xxxxx,
messagingSenderId: xxxxx,
;// your config object could be differ
```

`const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp(config);
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));`

```
const db = admin.database();
const action = request.body.queryResult.action;
if (action === 'product_description') {
    const product = request.body.queryResult.parameters.Products.trim();
    const ref = db.ref(`products/${product.toLowerCase()}/description`);
    ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        const result = snapshot.val();
        if (result === null) {
            response.json({
                fulfillmentText: `Product does not exists in inventory`
            });
            return;
        }
        response.json({
            fulfillmentText: `Here is the description of ${product}: ${result}`,
            source: action
        });

    }).catch((err) => {
        response.json({
            fulfillmentText: `I don't know what is it`
        });

    });
} else if(action === 'product_quantity') {
    const product = request.body.queryResult.parameters.Products.trim();
    const ref = db.ref(`products/${product.toLowerCase()}`);
    ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        const result = snapshot.val();
        if (result === null) {
            response.json({
                fulfillmentText: `Product does not exists in inventory`
            });
            return;
        }
        if (!result.stock) {
            response.json({
                fulfillmentText: `Currently ${product} is out of stock`,
                source: action
            });
        } else {
            response.json({
                fulfillmentText: `We have ${result.stock} ${product} in stock`,
                source: action
            });
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        response.json({
            fulfillmentText: `I don't know what is it`
        });
    });
} else {
    response.json({
        fulfillmentText: `I don't know what is it`
    });
}
```

});`

This is the my package.json

`{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents      using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.12.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "dialogflow": "^0.12.1",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"
  }
}`

Comment: Is there some reason that initializing the Admin SDK with the default settings won't work for you?  `admin.initializeApp()` with no arguments is the standard usage when you need to access resources in the same project as the function.

Comment: I am not sure whether the default settings are working as intended. Since i define config to store all the api key, projectid etc.